# Syntax for drush command civicrm-sql-dump

Tags: drupal, database, mysql, drush, backups

My attempt to backup my civicrm database using `mysqldump` has failed after a very rocky CiviCRM upgrade process, or it is taking way too long, so I am trying the drush command, `drush civicrm-sql-dump` in drush 7.0.0 on what I hope is finally CiviCRM 4.7.13 but the command is just dumping to the screen. What other information should I provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `drush civicrm-sql-dump --help` the output is:

```
Prints the whole CiviCRM database to STDOUT or save to a file.

Examples:
 drush civicrm-sql-dump        Save SQL dump to the directory above Drupal root. 
 --result-file=../CiviCRM.sql

Options:
 --data-only                               Dump data without statements to create any of the schema.             
 --gzip                                    Compress the dump using the gzip program which must be in your $PATH. 
 --result-file                             Save to a file.                                                       
 --tables-list                             comma-separated list of tables to transfer.
```

So since you want it in a file rather than on your screen, use the `--result-file` option and tell it what file you want to write to.

Comment: If the default behavior is to print to the screen, then the help text is wrong - it claims to save `"to the directory above Drupal root."`

Comment: Or is that help text supposed to apply to the full command with `--result-file` argument included?  The formatting makes that unclear.

Comment: ``"to the directory above Drupal root."`` is the help text for the example command that includes ``--result-file=../CiviCRM.sql``  I agree the formatting could be better... and that help text assumes you are running the command from Drupal root.